# How to modify SKAnnotation annotationView in SKMaps?

Tags: ios, objective-c, skmaps

I want to udpate the annotation on select of the annotation.
How do I do this in SKMaps for iOS?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [updateAnnotation](http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/ios/2.3.0/Classes/SKMapView.html#//api/name/updateAnnotation:) API - with this you can change all the parameters (but the position on the screen).

Comment: I am trying to update the annotationView of the annotation on didSelectAnnotation: method.
Its not getting reflected though,     
[mapView updateAnnotation:annotation]; returns true.

Comment: Please add the complete code snippet that you are using when calling updateAnnotation - what properties of the annotation are you changing?

Comment: I updated the sdk to the latest one and everything works fine now.